# Stop command is excuting from web browser console

Tags: javascript, browser, web

i would like to execute a loop in chrome console ,but i want to stop it when it is running (without closing web browser).So how to do that . Thanks much for any helps .

This is my script ,i want to stop this:

```
for(var i=0;i<20;i++) {
    (function (i) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            {
                scrollBy(1500, 999999);
            }
        }, 8000 * i);
    }(i));
};
setTimeout(function () {
    alert('Finish--------------!');
}, 8000 * (i));
```

Comment: Can you provide a little more detail? Are you trying to achieve this with javascript or chrome developer tools?  For all intents and purposes, javascript is single-threaded and looping operations are blocking. So if you're trying to write a function that allows you to break iteration based on a change to the global state that has taken place in the same time domain as the iterative processes you're trying to break from, you're going to have to hack something together that is very specific to your implementation.

Comment: Thanks .I run it use browser console ,ctr+shift+j and paste code ,could you help me a code can stop or exit that script ? .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong but I think you're trying to clear the timeout objects rather than stop the loop.

Try something like this:

```
var obj = [];

for(var i=0;i<20;i++) {
    (function (i) {
        obj.push(setTimeout(function () {
            {
                scrollBy(1500, 999999);
            }
        }, 8000 * i));
    }(i));
}

obj.push(setTimeout(function () {
    alert('Finish--------------!');
}, 8000 * (i)));

// when this function is called it will loop over the timeout objects
// you created in the above loop and clear them
function clearTO() {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < obj.length; i += 1) {
        clearTimeout(obj[i]);
    }
}

// if typing 'yes' in the prompt gives you the behavior 
// you're looking for replace this timeout function with something more dynamic that fits your needs


var cnt = 0;
function stop() {
    if (prompt("type yes to stop") === "yes") {
        clearTO();
    } else if(cnt < i){
        cnt += 1;
        setTimeout(stop, 8010);
    };
}


stop();
```

Obviously You'll have to bind clearTO() to an event of some kind.

Comment: Thanks .I am checking it .seems complicated ..(-_0)

Comment: I changed the prompt function to be more useful. I realise using `prompt` isn't ideal, but I just wanted to know if the "yes" prompt gives you the type of behaviour you're looking for.

Comment: my friend ,it does not stop the alert box

Comment: Glad to help. Conceptually I think it's important that you understand that the initial loop completes in less than a millisecond. `setTimeout` is an asynchronous operation, so the loop does NOT wait for it to run the function, it pretty much says "do this stuff later when I'm not performing a blocking operation" and skips over it.

Comment: Calls to `setTimeout` return an Object that represents the task you'd like to perform. The only changes I made to your code was that I put all of these timeout Objects into an Array so that you could reference them later and call `clearTimeout` on them. It's really important that you have at least a conceptual understanding of what's going on with javascript asynchronous functions because implementing asynchronous functions while expecting synchronous behavior will cause extremely confusing errors.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this another function structure:
eg.

```
//CODE WILL STOP WHEN PAGE IS NEARLY END
var i=0;
function someFunc() {
setTimeout(function () {
        {
            scrollBy(0, 200);
        }
    }, 8000 * i);
i++;
if($(window).height()-window.pageYOffset < 200) i=20;
if(i<20) someFunc();
}
someFunc();
```

Comment: Thanks .but i dont get what you mean ,i am running that code ,and i need another code could stop it ,or exit it

Comment: So if you wanna stop executing fast, simply change i to 20.

Comment: yes ,that is so right ,i use this : "javascript: var i=20 ; "  ,but it still run ,dear

Comment: But when you wanna stop executing ?

Comment: Up you have the code executed until i<2... just change this number to whatever you want to stop executing when i<5 or i<10. i dont know how many time you want to execute it

Comment: it seems you misunderstanding a bit ,i mean that when it is running ,and i want to stop it at that time ,at a time that i dont know i=? ,just i want to stop it at that time ,no change code any more ,just write another code so that can exit or stop that function

Comment: simply refresh the page

Comment: my friend , that code will scroll a page ,until i see page nearly come to end ,i will push a code stop ,but this page is different from other pages ,when will page come to end ,you dont know ,so you dont know value of  ' i '

Comment: Oh so your argument about which function will stop is the page scroll position ?

Comment: You need to operate window.pageYOffset and window.pageXOffset. It will show you your page position. You can write function something like
when windowYSize minus window.pageYOffset is smaller than 200 then stop function.

Comment: Thanks Damian for all .